# Weighted bins in a distribution hist plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I'm looking for a way to plot a distribution histogram, with the `y-axis` representing the total number of items for each bin (and not just the count).

Example on the charts below:

- On the left, there are 55 agencies who sold between 20-30 houses
- On the right, the agencies having sold between 20-30 houses represent 1100 houses sold

[image]

It's not as trivial as it looks because one can't simply multiply each bin's count by the bin's value (maybe in the 20-30 bin, there are 54 agencies who sold 21 are 1 who sold 29).

**Questions:**

- What is the name of such a chart (the one on the right)?
- Is there a way to plot it natively in `matplotlib` or `seaborn`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to use the `weights` kwarg (see [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy-histogram)) which is passed through `ax.hist` ([see](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist)).

Something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(num_sold, bins, weights=num_sold)
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks. So, is the name of this chart a... *weighted histogram*?

Comment: Second link is dead!

Comment: And note that for Poisson bin uncertainties you'd need to inflate the error bars too.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: @tacaswell is better use it. But the labels for mine will line up correctly without hassle and the bars will be separated.

Hopefully your data is in pandas. I will create some fake data and then give you a solution.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe of number of homes sold
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'sold':np.random.randint(0,100, 1000)})

# groupby the left side of interval [0, 10), [10, 20) etc..  and plot
df.groupby(df.sold // 10 * 10).sum().plot.bar()
```