# How to center labels in histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a following problem. I need to center labes on the X axis on my plt.hist(). I found some answer here: [How to center labels in histogram plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246125/how-to-center-labels-in-histogram-plot) that recommends to use `align = "left/mid/right"` . However, it does not give me the right output:

`plt.hist(data['Col1'], align='left')`
[image]

`plt.hist(data['Col1'], align='mid')`
[image]

`plt.hist(data['Col1'], align='right')`
[image]

I want to have the `ok` and `18 let` exactly in the middle of each bar. How can I fix it please?

Whole code:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
plt.suptitle('My histogram', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontweight='bold')


plt.hist(data['Col1'], align='mid')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Code? It seems you're doing it right, but you have an extra bin and throws the alignment off.

Comment: I put it below, thanks for reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matplotlib's `hist()` with default parameters is mainly meant for continuous data.
When no parameters are given, matplotlib divides the range of values into 10 equally-sized bins.

When given string-data, matplotlib internally replaces the strings with numbers `0, 1, 2, ...`. In this case, "ok" got value `0` and "18 let" got value `1`. Dividing that range into  10, creates 10 bins: `0.0-0.1, 0.1-0.2, ..., 0.9-1.0`.  Bars are put at the bin centers (`0.05, 0.15, ..., 0.95`)  and default aligned `'mid'`. (This centering helps when you'd want to draw narrower bars.)  In this case all but the first and last bar will have height `0`.

Here is a visualization of what's happening. Vertical lines show where the bin boundaries were placed.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.random.choice(['ok', '18 let'], 10, p=[0.2, 0.8])})

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontweight='bold')

_counts, bin_boundaries, _patches = ax.hist(data['Col1'])
for i in bin_boundaries:
    ax.axvline(i, color='navy', ls='--')
    ax.text(i, 1.01, f'{i:.1f}', transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), ha='center', va='bottom', color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: visualizing plt.hist]

To have more control over a histogram for discrete data, it is best to give explicit bins, nicely around the given values (e.g. `plt.hist(..., bins=[-0.5, 0.5, 1.5])`). A better approach is to create a count plot: count the individual values and draw a bar plot (a histogram just is a specific type of bar plot).

Here is an example of such a "count plot". (Note that the `return_counts=` parameter of numpy's [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) is only available for newer versions, 1.9 and up.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.random.choice(['ok', '18 let'], 10, p=[0.2, 0.8])})

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.locator_params(axis='y', integer=True)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontweight='bold')

labels, counts = np.unique(data['Col1'], return_counts=True)
plt.bar(labels, counts)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with counts]

Note that seaborn's [`histplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) copes better with discrete data. When working with strings or when explicitly setting `discrete=True`, appropriate bins are automatically calculated.