# How to center bin ticks in matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a histogram but somehow my ticks are not correct.
I need that ticks will be in the center of the histogram bars.
I was trying to use `align="mid"` but it didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data_trough_min = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['month'])

month = []
for i in range(0,7942):
    n = random.randint(1,12)
    month.append(n)
print(month)
    
data_trough_min['month'] = month

def bins_labels(bins, **kwargs):
    bin_w = (max(bins) - min(bins)) / (len(bins) - 1)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(bins)+bin_w/2, max(bins), bin_w), bins, **kwargs)
    plt.xlim(bins[0], bins[-1])


plt.hist(data_trough_min.month, weights=np.zeros_like(data_trough_min.month) + 1. / data_trough_min.month.size, bins=12, histtype='bar', ec='black', density = True,
          rwidth=0.7)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
bins = range(1,13)
bins_labels(bins, fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(bins,)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
```

[image]

How can I set up the histogram such that all of the xticks are aligned in the center?
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hope this solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246125/how-to-center-labels-in-histogram-plot

Comment: Yes I was actually using that example, but I think when I use 'weights' it is not working well

Comment: You're using continuous bins for a discrete histogram. Seaborn usually is easier to use in these situations.